# How do I call an app route from python using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have 2 flask routes like so.

```
@app.route("/table", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def table() -> str:
    return "<table><thead><tr><th>HELLO</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>HOLA</td></tr></tbody></table>"

@app.route('/config', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def config() -> str:
    form = ConfigForm()
    return render_template(
        "product.html",
        form=form)
```

The config route calls ConfigForm which looks like so...

```
class ConfigForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = url_for("table")
```

For some reason, instead of self.table containing the html table in a string format, it contains `/table`.
Is it possible to call a flask route from python that will return a value?

Comment: `url_for` only generates the URL for the endpoint. This is why `self.table` contains the URL for `table`. To get the returned value of the endpoint, you should call it.

Comment: Forgive me for being a novice programmer but how would I go about calling it?

Answer (score 0):

This is because `url_for` returns url string for a particular method (in this case `table`)

Solution: Create a different method

```
def get_table_content() -> str:
    return "<table><thead><tr><th>HELLO</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>HOLA</td></tr></tbody></table>"

@app.route("/table", methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def table() -> str:
    return get_table_content()

@app.route('/config', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def config() -> str:
    form = ConfigForm()
    return render_template(
        "product.html",
        form=form)
```

and then below should work:

```
class ConfigForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = get_table_content()
```

Comment: @TonyAlexander: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem (you can do so by clicking the small check next to the answer which then turns green).